# Concatenate list and number in a sublist in Python

Tags: python, list

How do I concatenate a list such as this:

```
buttons = [[['a','b','c'], '2'], [['d','e','f'], '3']]
```

into

```
buttons = [[['a','b','c','2'], ['d','e','f','3']]]
```

I tried accessing three indexes and concatenating but it didn't work:

```
buttons[0][1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> l = [[['a','b','c'], '2'], [['d','e','f'], '3']]
>>> [list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(i)) for i in l]
[['a', 'b', 'c', '2'], ['d', 'e', 'f', '3']]
```

Answer (score 7):

One way is to unpack each element inside a list comprehension and concatenate the two parts:

```
>>> buttons = [[['a','b','c'], '2'], [['d','e','f'], '3']]
>>> [x + [y] for x, y in buttons]
[['a', 'b', 'c', '2'], ['d', 'e', 'f', '3']]
```

---

This works because for each sublist has two elements; the first element is assigned to `x`, the second element is assigned to `y`. For example, for the first sublist in `buttons` we have:

```
x, y = [['a','b','c'], '2']
```

So then:

```
>>> x
['a','b','c']
>>> y
'2'
```

These two parts are then joined together like this:

```
x + [y] == ['a', 'b', 'c'] + ['2'] == ['a', 'b', 'c', '2']
```

Comment: This is nice and elegant!

Comment: can someone explain how this works? I don't get how y is `['2'] and ['3']`

Comment: @SirParselot: added an explanation of the method.